# how to wait for a specific command to finish in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get some info from pages that look like this [link to the site](https://matchstat.com/tennis/player/Sergiy%20Stakhovsky)

I need to scroll all the way down, I wrote a function for that.

```
def Scroll(): 
    startPos = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
    while 1:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") #need to wait
        time.sleep(0.1)
        newPos = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
        if newPos == startPos:
            break
        startPos = newPos
return
```

I would like to change time.sleep(0.1) with some conditional wait until the line before that one is executed, is there a way to do this? There is no special element loaded after every scroll or at the end of the page.

Solution:

```
...
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
while 1:
    if driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"):
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        continue
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thread.sleep, you can use following code which waits for Ajax calls to complete because every scroll, there will be a Ajax call in the background.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
```

`Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnValue("return jQuery.active == 0"));`

Comment: Expected Conditions in python doesn't have "jsReturnValue". I don't know how exactly to make this with a 1-liner. But that statement in brackets was useful so thanks.